# VirtualBox VM with fixed IP and internet access

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I would like to setup an Ubuntu 14 in a Virtual Box so that I can access to a http server which runs in this VM from the host. However I need the IP of the VM to be fixed while VM shall also have access to the internet (mostly for apt-get and http).

Right now, I use bridged networking which gives me internet access, but IP changes every time the host (a laptop) connects to a different network.

Comment: You can set up two network interfaces for the virtual machine, one bridge to access the network from the VM, and one "host-only" to access the VM from the host, using a static IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go on parameter of the VM in VirtualBox, network, and check to have 2 interface. Choose "host-only". Then start your VM and configure the new interface to static IP : https://www.unixmen.com/setup-static-ip-ubuntu-14-04/